# How to avoid sending a bunch of requests to update data in DB

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have an unregistered user that works with my application, getting some progress. I keep this progress in local storage. Then, when the user decides to register, I send a PUT request to sync his progress with DB.

For that I track its `status` and when it's become `authenticated` and the `progress` parameter empty, I send a PUT request, but the problem is it sends dozens of PUT requests to update the progress instead of one.

```
'use client'
import { useSession, signIn, signOut, useUser } from 'next-auth/react'
import { use, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import AppContext from '../../utils/AppContext'

const updateProfile = async (email, prog) => {
  await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/${email}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      progress: prog,
    }),
  })
}

export default function Component() {
  const { progressArr, setProgressArr } = useContext(AppContext)
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  function updateUser() {
    use(updateProfile(session.user.email, progressArr))
  }

  if (status === 'authenticated') {
    if (!session.user.progress) {
      updateUser()
    }
  }

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

P.S. If it should be done in another way, share your ideas with me please.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the `updateUser()` with a throttle or debounce?

Comment: I tried to add `setTimeout` and put there `use(updateProfile(....))` but I get an error then: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Comment: If updateUser cannot be call in any hook, maybe you should change the approach. Why you use use with updateProfile? Is there another way without use?

Comment: It's a good question, I am not sure about another approach to update data in BD without a `use()` hook 

Comment: Do you clear the local storage entry upon updating the profile? 
BTW why don't you just update the profile after signing in? `signInAndUpdateProfile()`

Answer (score 2):

That could be the cause of multiple render cycles. Moving logic to `useEffect` might be

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'authenticated' && session?.user?.email && !session.user.progress) {
      updateProfile(session.user.email, progressArr)
    }
  }, [progressArr, status, session?.user?.email])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `updateUser` is called on "component render" so every time when your application changes state or any of parent components change state `updateUser` gets called.

Since this code introduces a side-effect for your component you can try to put this code into `useEffect` hook like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (status === 'authenticated') {
    if (!session.user.progress) {
      updateUser()
    }
  }
}, status);
```

However I won't recommend to keep components responsible for maintaining application state and handling side effects.

My recommendation would be to onboard you app with app-state management framework, like [redux](https://redux.js.org/) and move your data submission logic to [middleware](https://redux.js.org/understanding/history-and-design/middleware).
This way your data flow would look like:

1. User makes progress -> component dispatches event about progress made
2. Middleware picks up the event and based on authentication state either saves it to local storage or sends it to backend.

Comment: I can not use `use()` hook inside of `useEffect()`, getting error `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `updateUser()` is getting called multiple times by accident.
You could try to keep track of your request by adding something like `updateInProgress` as a state and set it to `true` once `updateUser()` is triggered and set it to `false` afterwards again.
After you’ve done this, you could just return if there is already an update in progress:

```js
async function updateUser() {
    if (updateInProgress) {
      return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below code:

```
export default function Component() {
  const { progressArr, setProgressArr } = useContext(AppContext)
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'authenticated' && !session.user.progress) {
      updateProfile(session.user.email, progressArr)
    }
  }, [progressArr])

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

using the `useEffect` hook to run the `updateUser()` by adding `[progressArr]` as the second argument to `useEffect`.

Note:
In theory `useContext` and `useSession` hooks to render sepcific contents (data) depending on authenticated user. It nice to implementing over authentication flow. `useEffect` hook is used to update the user's profile with the `progressArr` data if the user is authenticated and does not have a progress field in their profile. The updateProfile function is likely used to make an API call to update the user's profile.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: In theory useContext and useSession hooks to render sepcific contents (data) depending on authenticated user. It nice to  implementing over authentication flow.

useEffect hook is used to update the user's profile with the progressArr data if the user is authenticated and does not have a progress field in their profile. The updateProfile function is likely used to make an API call to update the user's profile.

Comment: Thanks for providing an explanation. You should add it to your question's text instead of as a comment though so that people can immediately review how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

There is **useEffect** hook to send a single request to update the progress of the user. **useEffect** hook is called when the **session**, status, or **progressArr** changes. If the user is authenticated and their progress is undefined, we call the **updateProfile**

Try this code. I think it will help you

```
'use client'
import { useSession, signIn, signOut, useUser } from 'next-auth/react'
import { use, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import AppContext from '../../utils/AppContext'

const updateProfile = async (email, progressArr) => {
  await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/${email}`, {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      progress: progressArr,
    }),
  })
}

export default function Component() {
  const { progressArr, setProgressArr } = useContext(AppContext)
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === 'authenticated' && session.user.progress === undefined) {
      updateProfile(session.user.email, progressArr)
    }
  }, [session, status, progressArr])

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  )
}
```